# Requests in django not able to send file

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django app which will use a file upload functionality and then send across the uploaded file to another web service, which is essentially a PHP page listening to the files sent to it. I am using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) to send along the uploaded file to the web service. However, when I see the logs in my web service, I see that the following files array received at the PHP page, no matter what I file I send:

```
Array
(
[file] => Array
 (
 [name] => file
 [type] =>  [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpAB43.tmp
  [error] => 0
  [size] => 1142
 )
)
```

I am sending along the file which is present in the directory specified by MEDIA_ROOT in settings.py. I have tried either of the two combinations of code, leading to the same output:

```
uploadedFile = request.FILES['uploadedFile'] 
files = {'file': open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+uploadedFile.name, 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

and

```
uploadedFile = request.FILES['uploadedFile']
files = {'file': uploadedFile}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I have checked that the file is indeed uploaded in the directory specified by MEDIA_ROOT. What is the probable reason for this to happen?

EDIT1: I should be getting the file which I sent in the list, something like

```
Array
(
[file] => Array
 (
 [name] => test.txt
 [type] => [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\phpAFDC.tmp
 [error] => 0
 [size] =>1142)

)
```

EDIT2: The PHP code receiving the file, which just prints out the array of files received in the request:

```
    $a = print_r($_FILES, true);
    fwrite(fopen("c:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\log1.txt", 'w'), $a);
```

EDIT3: I checked to see the file which was sent across and copied the file at the web service end. I changed the extension to .txt, which was the extension of the file being sent and it turns out it was the same file, without the extension and the name of the file being 'file'. That's odd, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is the problem? What are you expecting and what went wrong?

Comment: I am expecting the file which is sent to be received in the PHP file as well. But no matter what file i upload, I get 'file' as the filename in the array of uploaded files.

Comment: That is because you chose "file" as the key on the dict used for your `files` argument. It is always better to update your question instead of using the comment system.

Comment: I have updated my question. That's the key right, to retrieve the correct file from the list of uploaded files?

Comment: The temporary file name and size is always the same no matter what file you upload? I find it hard to believe.  Have you tried to send it from the REPL? Are you sure you are reloading your Django app every time you change the code?

Comment: The temporary file name changes, but the file size is the same. Shouldn't I receive the actual file name in the array of files uploaded? Instead, it just says 'file'. I am adding the PHP code in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding "EDIT1" I think you are wrong. The key in the `$_FILES` array is the field name from the form you used to send the file, not the original file name on your file system.

In order to test the issue, use the Django REPL:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> import requests
>>> files = {'foobar': open('/etc/passwd')}
>>> url = 'http://example.com/test.php'  # Replace by your URL here
>>> r = response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Then tell us if the size changed. If it changes, my guess is that you are changing the code but is not reloading the application. Note that Django is not like PHP where any change in the script is automatically reflected in the next request - if you are using a web server, changing the code may not affect the running instances of the WSGI application until you restart the process.

[edit]

You may want to set set the filename, content_type and headers explicitly:

```
files = {'file': (
    'yourfile.txt', 
    open('/path/to/yourfile.txt', 'rb'), 
    'text/plain', 
    {'Expires': '0'}
)}
```

Please do not trust `$_FILES['file']['name']` and never upload files to a path you are also serving on the web otherwise you will be asking to be pwned.

Comment: I tried the following in the shell. It is sending the correct file across. Not the same case when I try it from the django app. I have also tried restarting the server.

Comment: Gaurav, I'm trying to help. Did you read the bit about restarting the web server after you change the code? Also, did you noticed what I said about your expectation of the key of the `$_FILES` array being the name of the form field and not the original file name?

Comment: I have tried that, to no effect. Have also made another edit in that question. Somehow seems to me that the correct filename is not set across in the request, but the correct file is sent.

Comment: specifying the filename explicitely seemed to do the trick. thanks. :)